# node-rebuild error when installing React frontend on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, server, software-installation, nodejs, platform-integration

I am trying to install React frontend on Ubuntu 16.04. I am using node version-14.21.3 and npm version:6.14.18. I am also using node-gyp global version 9.4.0. I am still getting a node-gyp rebuild error. I am sharing the error code screenshot. Please help me to run the frontend part.
error code
[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V6VBZ.png)

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: If possible, can you tell that what issue exactly is there with the image I have shared here with node-gyp. Do I need to update node and npm? Please guide, I am stuck in this from a long time.

Comment: The oldest *supported* release of Ubuntu on-topic here is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Your system is that told even a *release-upgrade* won't bring you on-topic here, refer to my first comment and SE *Unix & Linux* is provided where your system is on-topic.